# Using a timer when a thread is running

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, timer

Ok so first off I am using visual basic 2010 and I have a thread that continuously loops to check for network requests from the remote clients. What I would like to do is when a client submits a certain request a timer will be triggered to start a countdown on the form, but for some reason I can't get the timer to start at all while the thread is running. I have also tried to abort the thread before starting the timer and that doesn't work either. Any help would be appreciated because I have been banging my head against the wall about this since last week.

```
Do While p1buzzedstatus = False Or p2buzzedstatus = False Or p3buzzedstatus = False
    'Download Communication File'
    Try
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
        Dim Aclient As New Net.WebClient
        Aclient.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(remote_buzzer_registration.FTPUserName, remote_buzzer_registration.FTPPassword)
        If Aclient.DownloadString(BuzzerCommandURL) = "" Then
            'Don't Do Anything'
        Else
            'Check For Buzz'
            keypressed = Aclient.DownloadString(BuzzerCommandURL)
            Aclient.UploadString(BuzzerCommandURL, "")
            buzzercode()
            answer_timer.Start()  ' <--- HERE
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
Loop
```

Comment: What kind of timer?  Can you show a short yet complete example of code that doesn't work?

Comment: this code runs without any exceptions; however, the tick event in the answer_timer never fires.

Comment: And what is answer_timer?  Is that a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`?

Comment: So, are you saying that you are trying to access a winforms timer from another thread than the thread that the form was created on? I don't think that would work. Winforms components are not possible to access from other threads. (Well, you may be able to do that using BeginInvoke). Maybe you could use ThreadPool instead to do your work?

Answer (score 3):

If your `answer_timer` is a WinForm timer control (`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`), then you cannot start it from any thread other than the UI thread.  Starting a WinForm timer control from another thread will not cause an exception, but it will not work at all either.

To start the timer properly, you can invoke the method on the UI thread like this:

```
Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf answer_timer.Start))
```

Alternatively, you could use either the `System.Timers.Timer` or the `System.Threading.Timer`.  Either of those work fine from any thread.  The one in `System.Timers` is the closest equivalent to the control.  However, since these other two timers tick via a new thread, the code that executes upon the timer tick will still need to invoke back to the UI thread before doing anything to the UI.  So, if your timer tick code is doing anything to the form or controls, it's probably easier to just stick with the WinForm timer control.

Comment: Steven Doggart you are THE MAN!!!!! invoking the method worked perfectly. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

At a guess: Your Timer is on a Windows Form and you are trying to use another Thread to update it?
When you try this, the event will not be triggered (the beheaviour is looking weird if I recall correctly). You are running into this issue because the UI thread cannot be updated by your second thread directly. You should try to use a delegate on your UI thread, which is called by your second thread.

You would simply wrap the Timer.start into a delegate.
Here is the catch: You will into problems again, if your timer shall do something on thread 2. So maybe it would be best to move the Timer to Thread 2 (dim timer as NEW windows.forms.timer) and run it there. In it's tick event it could raise a delegate to update the countdown...

Comment: ok I have this Dim timer as new windows.forms.timer but where do I put the timer tick code?

Comment: Create a new Procedure for your tick-code, then call addhandler (google it, sorry I am very busy at this moment :( ) to register that procedure with the tick-event.